# How to create a custom page template suggestions for a node type?

Tags: theming

My code like this.
[image]

But get Error!!!!!

[image]

Where the wrong??

Comment: Please post code as code, not as image. You want to make it easier, not harder for us to answer, right?

Answer (score 4):

[hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) will be run on every page, regardless of whether or not it is displaying a node, and `$variables['node']` is only defined when you are.  Thus, you need to wrap this with something like:

```
if (isset($variables['node'])) {

  // do stuff when displaying a node

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shown below is how I achieve custom page templates.

Using this method, the node of content type 'blog' would have the template of 'page--blog.tpl.php'

```
<?php 

function newyasi_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
  // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}

?>
```

I hope that is of some use to you, good luck.